# How to pass a variable to a function?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Sub called 
    sortRows(location As String, wksht As String)

The parameter wksheet is being passed to sortRows from another subroutine that is looping through spreadsheets.

I keep getting the error 
"Compile Error.
"Expected: = "

After some research I discovered ByRef directive(?) and re-wrote the Sub as
    sortRows(location As String, ByRef wksht As String)

But I still get the same error when calling it in the worksheet loop.

The Sub works fine, but I can't seem to get the call to it working properly.

I have tried two ways to call the Sub:
    sortRows ("Florida",sheetname)
    sortRows ("Florida", wksht:=sheetname)

Both ways result in a "Compile Error"

Comment: could you please show how do you call the function

Comment: please both the code for the sub from which you call sortRows and the sortRows sub itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little hard without seeing your full code.

But I suggest you try passing your worksheet variable as a worksheet, ie

There is a good reference here from Pearson [Passing Simple Variables ByRef And ByVal](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx)

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets(2)
Call sortRows("MyName", ws)
End Sub

Sub sortRows(location As String, ByRef ws1 As Worksheet)
MsgBox ws1.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks brettdj, that worked.
But I never would have guessed on the "Call" directive.
Any basics I should be studying?

Comment: @KenIngram I have added a link above, rgds DB